# Wakeup Ubuntu 13.04 with usb keyboard

Tags: usb, wakeup

I am trying to wakeup my laptop using a wireless keyboard. Therefor I need to enable usb wakeup. Can anybode make a very easy-to-follow guide.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there can be a guide since you did not post your PC motherboard type or laptop model. From what I know a USB wake up is made from bios.